# The service "redirect.request subscriber" has a dependency on a non-existent service "path.alias_manager"

Tags: 9, upgrading

While upgrading D8.9 to D9.1 got the below issue. Tired all solution nothing works. Because on this issue site is down and unable to process anything.

> [php7:notice] [pid 26850] Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: The service "redirect.request_subscriber" has a dependency on a non-existent service "path.alias_manager". in /var/www/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php on line 86

Could anyone faced this issue or how to overcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal 8.8 `path.alias_manager` was deprecated and in Drupal 9 it was removed. You need to update the [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module to a version compatible with Drupal 9.

The current version contains the correct service definition having `path_alias.manager` as dependency:

*modules/contrib/redirect/redirect.services.yml*

```
redirect.request_subscriber:
  class: Drupal\redirect\EventSubscriber\RedirectRequestSubscriber
  arguments: ['@redirect.repository', '@language_manager', '@config.factory', '@path_alias.manager', '@module_handler', '@entity_type.manager', '@redirect.checker', '@router.request_context', '@path_processor_manager']
  tags:
    - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Answer (score 0):

One or more of your modules use "path.alias_manager" instead of "path_alias_manager". It will not necessarily be the Redirect module. Just look for the string "path.alias_manager" in your files and you will know which module needs updating. In my case it was module Cookiebot. There might be other ones.

Comment: The service "redirect.request subscriber" in the question *is* from the module Redirect. If you get this error for a different service it should point you to the module, modules name their services starting with the module name.